# Search Engines indexing dynamic pages

Tags: json, search, seo

I am building a web site that will have multiple pages that are dynamically generated based on JSON data. How do I ensure that search engines will index my dynamic pages?

Thanks,

K.

Comment: Can you explain/describe more precisely how your application is working? most important part: what URL schemas are you using to locate your contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google now parses JavaScript](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2014/05/understanding-web-pages-better.html). As long as your JavaScript code is available for Googlebot to find and parse Google *should* be able to index those pages properly.

Comment: Any recommendations for converting database or Excel data to JSON?

Comment: It isn't tough to do depending on the server-side language of your choice. In PHP you just need to get that data into an array and then call `json_encode()` on that array.

Comment: Google won't parse and understand every content generated by JS. It mostly depends on URL (without fragment "#"). If you use URL correctly it might work. If you have all your contents on the same URL it won't.

Comment: Should I add a mod rewrite to the URLs?

Comment: That isn't necessary for SEO but if you have a business reason for doing it, then go right ahead.